# How to get the desire ouput using bash script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to get this ouput, i don't know how to get it i search through the internet but i didn't know what will be the exact keyword for searching, so i post it here my question
i have a csv file `data.csv` which it contents are shown below
I have tried so far is shown my MWE

`cat data.csv|sed 's/\n.*//g'`

```
10,1,1,"line 1 text"
10,1,2,"line 2 text"
10,1,3,"line 3 text"
10,1,4,"line 4 text"
10,1,5, 
line 5 text
10,1,6,"<J>
 line 6 text"
10,1,7,"line 7 text"
10,1,8,"
 line 8 text"
10,1,9,"line 9 text"
```

I want the ouput as shown below

```
10,1,1,"line 1 text"
10,1,2,"line 2 text"
10,1,3,"line 3 text"
10,1,4,"line 4 text"
10,1,5,"line 5 text"
10,1,6,"<J>line 6 text"
10,1,7,"line 7 text"
10,1,8,"line 8 text"
10,1,9,"line 9 text"
```

Comment: I am new to shell scripting @jenesaisquoi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for mult-char RS, RT, and gensub() you can just describe each record as a series of 4 comma-separated fields ending in newline and then remove the newlines and spaces around them:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^,]*,){3}[^,]*\n' '{$0=gensub(/\s*\n\s*/,"","g",RT)} 1' file
10,1,1,"line 1 text"
10,1,2,"line 2 text"
10,1,3,"line 3 text"
10,1,4,"line 4 text"
10,1,5,line 5 text
10,1,6,"<J>line 6 text"
10,1,7,"line 7 text"
10,1,8,"line 8 text"
10,1,9,"line 9 text"
```

and to ensure quotes around the last field:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^,]*,){3}[^,]*\n' '{$0=gensub(/\s*\n\s*/,"","g",RT); $0=gensub(/,([^",]*)$/,",\"\\1\"",1)} 1' file
10,1,1,"line 1 text"
10,1,2,"line 2 text"
10,1,3,"line 3 text"
10,1,4,"line 4 text"
10,1,5,"line 5 text"
10,1,6,"<J>line 6 text"
10,1,7,"line 7 text"
10,1,8,"line 8 text"
10,1,9,"line 9 text"
```

Note that this will work no matter how many lines your 4th field is split over:

```
$ cat file
10,1,1,"line 1 text"
10,1,2,
foo
line
2
text
bar
10,1,3,"line 3 text"

$ awk -v RS='([^,]*,){3}[^,]*\n' '{$0=gensub(/\s*\n\s*/,"","g",RT); $0=gensub(/,([^",]*)$/,",\"\\1\"",1)} 1' file
10,1,1,"line 1 text"
10,1,2,"fooline2textbar"
10,1,3,"line 3 text"
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/".*"$/!{N;s/\n *//}' file
```

If a line does not match regex `".*"$` append next line (`N`) to sed's pattern space and replace newline followed by none, one or more white spaces with nothing (`s/\n *//`).

Output:

```
10,1,1,"line 1 text"
10,1,2,"line 2 text"
10,1,3,"line 3 text"
10,1,4,"line 4 text"
10,1,5, line 5 text
10,1,6,"line 6 text"
10,1,7,"line 7 text"
10,1,8,"line 8 text"
10,1,9,"line 9 text"
```

I did not add the missing quotation marks in line 5.

---

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: The first expression was the important one, so it warrants the nod.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Cyrus's answer, to ensure `'line 5 text'` is surrounded with *double-quotes* you can add additional expressions to replace the `', '` with `',"'` and lines that do not end in `'"'` with a `'"'`, e.g.

```
sed -e '/".*"$/!{N;s/\n *//}' -e 's/, /,"/' -e '/"$/!{s/$/"/}' file
```

The first expression is exactly the same. This would provide your requested output of:

```
$ sed -e '/".*"$/!{N;s/\n *//}' -e 's/, /,"/' -e '/"$/!{s/$/"/}' file
10,1,1,"line 1 text"
10,1,2,"line 2 text"
10,1,3,"line 3 text"
10,1,4,"line 4 text"
10,1,5,"line 5 text"
10,1,6,"<J>line 6 text"
10,1,7,"line 7 text"
10,1,8,"line 8 text"
10,1,9,"line 9 text"
```